# GSL numerical integration: increase sampling around list of points?

Tags: numerical-methods, gsl

I want to integrate a function on a finite interval. I know the positions of "interesting" peaks of this function, and I know that the function is almost zero except in the vicinity of these peaks. The peaks are not singularities, in the sense that the function is smooth all around. However, the peaks are very sharp.

I know that numerical integration routines in GSL admit a list of "singularities". However, I am wondering if this is what I need to use, since as I mentioned, the function is smooth. So how do I specify a list of peaks such that the sampling is denser in the vicinity of the peaks?

Comment: If you know the location of the peaks, why not just split the integration in multiple intervals in order to isolate the peaks?